# The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format. Swift 5

Tags: ios, json, swift, api, jsondecoder

I am trying to decode data from https://swapi.dev/. I get json correctly with response code 200, but the decoder could not read the data because the format is incorrect. I tried it in a lot of different ways. I am trying to get info on peoples.

Here is my code:

**Model File**

```
struct people: Codable {
    let count: Int
    let next: String?
    let previous: String?
    let results: [result]
}

struct result: Codable{
    let name: String
    let height: Int
    let mass: Int
    let hair_color: String
    let skin_color: String
    let eye_color: String
    let birth_year: String
    let gender: String
    let homeworld: String
    let films: [String]
    let species: [String]
    let vehicles: [String]
    let starships: [String]
    let created: String
    let edited: String
    let url: String
    
}

struct APIError: Codable {
    let detail: String
}
```

**Network Services**

```
typealias OnApiSucces = (people) -> Void
typealias OnApiError = (String) -> Void

struct ApiService {
    static let shared = ApiService()
    
    let URL_BASE = "https://swapi.dev/api"
    let URL_PEOPLE = "/people"
    
    let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
    

    
    func getResults(onSuccess: @escaping OnApiSucces, onError: @escaping OnApiError) {

        let url = URL(string: "\(URL_BASE)\(URL_PEOPLE)")!
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "GET" // GET, PUT, POST, DELETE for some different api
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

                if let error = error {
                    onError(error.localizedDescription)
                    return
                }

                guard let data = data, let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
                    onError("Invalid data or response")
                    return
                }

                do{
                    if response.statusCode == 200 {
                        print("Code is \(response.statusCode)")
                        let results = try JSONDecoder().decode(people.self, from: data)
                        onSuccess(results)
                    } else {
                        let err = try JSONDecoder().decode(APIError.self, from: data)
                        print("Code is \(response.statusCode)")
                        onError(err.detail)
                    }
                }
                catch {
                    onError(error.localizedDescription)
                }

            }
        task.resume()

        }

    }
```

** Getting data on ViewController**

```
    func getResults() {
        ApiService.shared.getResults { (people) in
            self.results = people.results
        } onError: { (error) in
            debugPrint(error.description)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Tip: paste your resulting JSON into https://app.quicktype.io to get generated model structs

Comment: Never print `error.localizedDescription` in a `JSONDecoder` catch block, the error message is pretty meaningless. Print `error`, it shows you the real comprehensible error. And in JSON everything wrapped in double quotes is `String` even `"123"` or `"false"`.

Comment: Thanks! I changed to String and it works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your data can't be read because `height` and `mass` are represented as `String` in the Star Wars API, while you represent them as `Int` in your `Codable` struct.

Also, try adding `CodingKeys` to your `Codable` struct so your struct adheres to naming conventions (specifically regarding your `attribute_color` variants) e.g.

```
struct result: Codable{
    let name: String
    let height: String
    let mass: String
    let hairColor: String  // changed from hair_color
    let skinColor: String
    let eyeColor: String
    let birthYear: String
    let gender: String
    let homeworld: String
    let films: [String]
    let species: [String]
    let vehicles: [String]
    let starships: [String]
    let created: String
    let edited: String
    let url: String
    enums CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
      case name = "name"
      case height = "height"
      case mass = "mass"
      case hairColor = "hair_color"
      case skinColor = "skin_color"
      case eyeColor = "eye_color"
      case birthYear = "birth_year"
      case gender = "gender"
      case homeworld = "homeworld"
      case films = "films"
      case species = "species"
      case vehicles = "vehicles"
      case starships = "starships"
      case created = "created"
      case edited = "edited"
      case url = "url" 
    }
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, use `JSONDecoder.KeyDecodingStrategy.convertFromSnakeCase` if the mapping is as simple as this.

Comment: Working with changed type to String.